# GridSearchCV - access to predicted values across tests?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

Is there a way to get access to the predicted values calculated within a GridSearchCV process?

I'd like to be able to plot the predicted y values against their actual values (from the test/validation set).

Once the grid search is complete, I can fit it against some other data using

```
 ypred = grid.predict(xv)
```

but I'd like to be able to plot the values calculated during the grid search. Maybe there's a way of saving the points as a pandas dataframe?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold, 
cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVR

scaler = StandardScaler()
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf')
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', scaler), ('svr_rbf', svr_rbf)])
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=parameters, cv=splits, refit=True, verbose=3, scoring=msescorer, n_jobs=4)
grid.fit(xt, yt)
```

Comment: As far, as I am concerned you cannot do that (but I might be wrong). The solution that I can think of is to predict values for each parameter configuration individually. However, this won't replicate the `GridSearchCV`, since your test/train samples will be different (especially with KFoldValidation). You can maybe try to plot the `mean_test_score` for range of each parameter value, keeping all other parameters constant. Although, it is also not optimal since different parameter configurations affect each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get predictions for each set of parameters using GridSearchCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602518/how-to-get-predictions-for-each-set-of-parameters-using-gridsearchcv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to make a custom scorer and save an argument it receives into a global variable:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error,make_scorer

X, y = np.random.rand(2,200)
clf = SVR()

ys = []

def MSE(y_true,y_pred):
    global ys
    ys.append(y_pred)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    return mse

def scorer():
    return make_scorer(MSE, greater_is_better=False)

n_splits = 3 
cv = GridSearchCV(clf, {'degree':[1,2,3]}, scoring=scorer(), cv=n_splits)
cv.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y)
```

Then we need to collect every split into a full array:

```
idxs = range(0, len(ys)+1, n_splits)
#e.g. [0, 3, 6, 9]
#collect every n_split elements into a single list
new = [ys[j[0]+1:j[1]] for j in zip(idxs,idxs[1:])]
#summing every such list
ys = [reduce(lambda x,y:np.concatenate((x,y), axis=0), i) for i in new]
```

Comment: If I use parameter `n_jobs` when instantiating `GridSearchCV`, this doesn't work. Also, I get `y_pred`, but I would like to get `y_pred_proba`. Any workaround?

Comment: @DennyCeccon did you find a solution?

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer yes I did! Let me post it below.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for using more than one processor and storing `y_pred_proba` instead of `y_pred`.

First we need to start a multiprocessing manager:

```
import multiprocessing
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
```

Before instantiating `GridSearchCV`, we need to create a dummy scorer, that will capture and store the values of the probabilities. In my case, I used ROC_AUC, but any metric will work:

```
scorers = {}
def roc_auc_dummy(y_true, y_pred_proba):
    global ys # This will make sure `ys` is in the global, not local, scope
    ys.append(y_pred_proba)
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_proba)
    return roc_auc
scorers['roc_auc'] = make_scorer(roc_auc_dummy, needs_proba = True)
```

`scorers` can have other scoring functions as fits your needs. Then, we need to create a list using the manager, instantiate `GridSearchCV`, and fit it.

```
ys = manager.list()
clf = GridSearchCV(model, params, scoring = scorers)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

The probabilities can be retrieved converting `ys` to a list:

```
y_pred_probas = list(ys)
```

`y_pred_probas` will be a list of lists, in which each internal list will be in the same order as in `clf.cv_results_['params']`.